# Use Querystring to define result source for searching

Tags: query-string, result-source

I am migrating a site from SP2010 to SP2013. One of page contain a search result webpart. By define the querystring like this:

```
SearchResult.aspx?k=Scope:Hotnews
```

It will return only the defined scope results.

However, since SP2013 no longer provide Scope, can I perform similiar trick with querystring? I have setup a Result Source "Hotnews" on my SP2013 farm. But I don't know how to make it work in querystring way.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Mark it's hard to find documentation for this but at the end I resolved using this pattern:

```
resultspage.aspx#Default={"k":"*","r":[{"n":"owstaxIdYourManagedProp","t":["cf32e33f-7ca2-470d-956b-29368e54e736"],"o":"OR","k":false,"m":{"cf32e33f-7ca2-470d-956b-29368e54e736":"TermName"}}]}
```

It's important to note that: k:* basically it means "all documents" owstaxIdXXX is a typical name of managed property mapped to a termset cf32e33f-7ca2-470d-956b-29368e54e736 is an example of termID inside your termstore TermName is an example of term name inside your termstore